# SharePoint 2013 referencing old url after Migration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

Recently migrated my SharePoint server 2010 to the 2013 version. The migration was done from one domain to another. All users were migrated successfully and they can all log in to the site accept the my account which I have a way around and does not disturb me that much. When users log in to the SharePoint it also pops the login window with the old site url asking you to login when cancelled it works fine. How do I get rid of the old site login reference. It is really annoying to the users.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely culprit here is that something on your page is hard coded to the old absolute URL.  Check your Master Page, any custom CSS, or any custom JavaScript to ensure that there are no hard coded references.